# Making new array of specific data from output of another function

Tags: php

I am running a PHP based telnet session vs a piece of equipment I have getting the interfaces that it contains. What I would like to do is remove the bold values below, every one is 8-10 numerical characters and always ends in "103", and place them in a new array. Each line is a string in an array returned by the telnet class.

I believe the statement ([0-9]{4,7}103) should grab the correct numbers but I am horrible at those and always seem to mess the up.

So for the code:

```
foreach ($Data as $row)
{
    echo $row . '<br>';
}
```

I get the return of:

> 1/12 **31499103** 0 0 1 1/12, 2/29, 3/17, 4/2 , 
>   4/20, 5/13
>   1/13 **303710103** 0 0 1 1/13, 2/13, 3/13, 5/12,
>   7/14
>   1/14 **511230103** 0 0 1 1/14, 4/17, 6/19, 8/10
>   1/15 **661839103** 0 0 1 1/15, 2/15
>   1/16 **311493103** 0 0 1 1/16, 2/16
>   1/17 **3101316103** 0 0 1 1/17, 3/12, 4/19, 8/31,
>   10/12
>           1/18 **311800103** 0 0 1 1/18, 1/19, 2/18, 7/28,
>   7/29, 8/27, 9/14, 9/25,
>   9/29,10/1
>   1/20 **312135103** / **312136103** 0 0 1 1/20, 1/21, 2/21
>   1/22 **31338103** 0 0 1 1/22, 2/22, 4/23
>   1/23 **346585103** 0 0 1 1/23, 2/30, 3/30

I'm assuming inside the foreach I could add some sort of a "$newarray[] =" but I don't know what to use to get only the needed value, no spaces or letters to the sides of it, and each row from the output may not have anything or some may have two sets of which each number would need its own entry in the new array.

Thank you ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

```
$oldArray = array();
$newArray = array();

$pattern = "/(.*)(\s[0-9]*103\s)(.*)/";

foreach ($data as $row) {

    if (preg_match($pattern, $row, $matches) != 0) {
        $oldArray[] = $matches[1] . ' ' . $matches[3];
        $newArray[] = trim($matches[2]);
    } else {
        $oldArray[] = $row;
    }
}
```

$oldArray:

```
1/12 0 0 1 1/12, 2/29, 3/17, 4/2 , 
1/13 0 0 1 1/13, 2/13, 3/13, 5/12,
1/14 0 0 1 1/14, 4/17, 6/19, 8/10
1/15 0 0 1 1/15, 2/15
1/16 0 0 1 1/16, 2/16
1/17 0 0 1 1/17, 3/12, 4/19, 8/31,
1/18 0 0 1 1/18, 1/19, 2/18, 7/28,
1/20 312135103 / 0 0 1 1/20, 1/21, 2/21
1/22 0 0 1 1/22, 2/22, 4/23
1/23 0 0 1 1/23, 2/30, 3/30
```

$newArray:

```
31499103
303710103
511230103
661839103
311493103
3101316103
311800103
312136103
31338103
346585103
```

Comment: I just noticed that there is still 312135103 value in the old array. You should modify regex pattern (\s[0-9]*103\s) to catch only one value ending with 103 or two values ending 103 seperated with forward slash if they exist. You may want to var_dump $matches to see what's going on with your pattern. Good luck!